# How to let exim use smarthost when direct delivery fails

Tags: linux, smtp, exim, exim4, smarthost

I setup exim in order to send messages via a smarthost when the recipient domain is in a specific list, otherwise the delivery is direct via remote SMTP.
Once in a while some remote smtp server refuses the connection with error messages like `554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [XX.YY.ZZ.KK] blocked using *.zen.dq.spamhaus.net` and the submitter gets the error message of the failed delivery.

I would like to let exim automatically use the smarthost when error from remote smtp is 5.7.1.
Is this possible?
Thank you very much